# Why would it be necessary to give a docker container access to the docker socket?

Tags: docker, unix-socket

I am reading a docker run command where it maps `/var/run/docker.sock`
like:

```bash
docker run -it --net=host --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock theimage /bin/bash
```

Why would the container would need access to the socket? ([this article](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=17983623) says it is a very bad idea.)

What would be one case where the container need access to the socket?

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary until the container needs to invoke itself the docker daemon, for example, in order to create and run an inner container.

For example, in my CI chain Jenkins builds a docker image to run the build and test process. Inside it we need to create an image to test and then submit it to K8S. In such situation Jenkins, when builds the pipeline container, passes to it the docker socket to allow the container to create other containers using the host server docker daemon.